# Unable to connect to AWS SSM parameter using Spring boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-ssm

I want my spring boot application to connect AWS SSM parameter (Spring Boot Properties to an AWS System Manager Parameter Store)

While am starting my spring boot app, it throws the following error

```
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException: Config data resource '[AwsParamStoreConfigDataResource@34e20e6b context = '/config/application/', optional = false]' via location 'aws-parameterstore:' cannot be found
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.withLocation(ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.handle(ConfigDataImporter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processWithProfiles(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.rnd.aws.AwsApplication.main(AwsApplication.java:10)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:462)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:424)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.createSimpleSystemManagementClient(AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.java:82)
    at io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreConfigDataLocationResolver.createSimpleSystemManagementClient(AwsParamStoreConfigDataLocationResolver.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getInstance(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getOrElseThrow(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.get(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:88)
    at io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreConfigDataLoader.load(AwsParamStoreConfigDataLoader.java:38)
    at io.awspring.cloud.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreConfigDataLoader.load(AwsParamStoreConfigDataLoader.java:33)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
11:52:05.333 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
```

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Config data resource '[AwsParamStoreConfigDataResource@34e20e6b context = '/config/application/', optional = false]' via location 'aws-parameterstore:' does not exist

Action:

Check that the value 'aws-parameterstore:' at class path resource [application.properties] - 5:22 is correct, or prefix it with 'optional:'

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Am using IDE:eclipse.

Comment: Looks like it's looking for `/config/application`, whereas the correct path is `/config/fahim_local`. Try setting the context appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Add this properties to your bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: fahim
  profiles:
    active: local
```